# cufon hover state sticking

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, hover, cufon

right off the bat i just want to pre-thank anyone who chimes in. stackoverflow makes me feel a little better about humanity.

PROBLEM: I have a 'single-page' site where the main content reloads via ajax but the nav and footer stay the same. I am using Cufon fonts for the nav and Jquery to attach a class "current" to the current link. For some reason the hover state is sticking even after the current class is removed and added to another link.

HTML:
`<nav id="banner"><ul><li><a>1</a></li><li><a>2</a></li></ul></nav>`

CUFON:
`Cufon.replace('#banner a',{fontFamily: 'Gotham-Book', fontStyle: 'normal', hover: true});`

CLICK FUNCTION:
`$("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#banner nav a.current").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
        return false;
    });`

CSS:
    `#banner {color: #000;}
    #banner a:hover {color: #be1e2c;}
    #banner nav ul li a.current {color: #be1e2c;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your click function after `$(this).addClass("current");` add `Cufon.refresh();`
This call is needed every time you make a change to Cufon text.